# Editing lines in a file using a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, centos

I am creating a bash script that installed VSFTPD / FTP. After the installation some configuration is required in the "/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf" file.

This includes making sure the following lines are set to this:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
```

What would be the best approach for scripting a way for these edits to be made post installation?

Comment: I would go with `sed`

Comment: Are those lines (with the same or different values) already in the default conf? That is, what are you changing *from* and *to*?

Comment: It can vary but that is the end result I need to get to.

Comment: Note that not all versions of `sed` support `sed -c`, with `gnu sed 4.2.2` I'm getting `sed: invalid option -- 'c'`. Also, if those keys are commented in the original file (or missing) the `sed` solution below will not give you the end result that you actually need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `sed` it's really powerfull, this bash file would change the values:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  path_to_conf="/path/to/vsftpd.conf"
  anonymous_=NEIN
  local_=JA
  chroot_=IDK

  sed -c -i "s/\("anonymous_enable" *= *\).*/\1$anonymous_/" $path_to_conf
  sed -c -i "s/\("local_enable" *= *\).*/\1$local_/" $path_to_conf
  sed -c -i "s/\("chroot_local_user" *= *\).*/\1$chroot_/" $path_to_conf
```

You could use a loop to get this done, if you have to change a lot of variables, but with only three keys it's nicer like this (in my opinion).